# JSON_VALUE error on azure data factory log analytics JSON files

Tags: json, parsing, logging, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to excute this SQL query from azure synapse analytics on-demand to parse JSON ADF log that are stored on blob storage (one line JSON for each run).
I am getting this error :

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ' ' is found at position 1458.

SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP 100
cast(r.filepath(3) as varchar(100)) as [FACTORIE_NAME]
,cast(r.filepath(4) as varchar(4)) as [year]
,cast(r.filepath(5) as varchar(2)) as [month]
,cast(r.filepath(6) as varchar(2)) as [day]
,cast(r.filepath(7) as varchar(2)) as [hour]
,cast(r.filepath(8) as varchar(2)) as [minute]
,JSON_VALUE(jsonContent, '$.runId') as [pipelineRunId]
,JSON_VALUE(jsonContent, '$.pipelineName') as [pipelineName]
FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://blobDemo.blob.core.windows.net/insights-logs-activityruns/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/*/RESOURCEGROUPS/*/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/*/y=*/m=*/d=*/h=*/m=*/*.json',
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
    FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
)
WITH (
    jsonContent varchar(MAX)
) AS [r]
WHERE   
    r.filepath(4) = 2021 and r.filepath(5) = 07 and r.filepath(6) = 22
```

I saw that the JSON line in the jsonContent column was  truncated. Is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: Try with "nvarchar(max)" instead of "varchar(max)" for jsonContent column. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Try with "jsonContent varchar(MAX) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8" as well. Perhaps you need to use UTF8 collation or you can alter database to set default collation so you don't have to specify it in each OPENROWSET WITH clause.

Comment: You can also check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#json-text-is-not-properly-formatted